# Computer-based cognitive tests

Tags: measurement, test, study-cognitive-sciences

Maybe someone can point me out on the computer-based set of tests to assess the cognitive abilities of the adults? I am looking for something like ETS cognitive tests KIT that can be used online for the research purposes.

Comment: SHRM http://www.shrm.org/templatestools/assessmentresources/shrmtestingcenter/products/pages/index.aspx ? In the same vein, SHL, Kenexa, and others.

Comment: Welcome to Psych.SE. Please take a look at our [help]. This seems like a question that might generate a big list of answers each being equally good (e.g., the [ANAM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Neuropsychological_Assessment_Metrics) probably meets your requirements). It might be better if you could focus your question more so that there is an objectively best answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will lead to a big list of answers.

Answer (score 2):

A quick Google search reveals a list of computer-based cognitive testing software. Apparently,

- [Cogstate computerized cognitive tests](https://www.cogstate.com/clinical-trials/computerized-cognitive-assessment/)

  > have been used in hundreds of clinical trials––guiding decision-making for safety and efficacy across many indications and all phases of development.
- [CANTAB Connect Research](http://www.cambridgecognition.com/products/cognitive-research)

  > is the world’s most validated, precise and reliable research software providing sensitive digital measures of cognitive function for all areas of brain research. Delivering leading neuroscience through our secure cloud platform, CANTAB Connect Research is an efficient and easy-to-use system providing insights into behaviours, underlying brain circuits and neurochemical systems and measurement of digital cognitive biomarkers.